# Selective query

Tags: mysql, select

I'm keeping a database of accesses to a website (origin ip, refrer and landing page) so i can do some analisys of visitors and which pages are more interesting and wich need work (amongst other things)

Now some visitor IPs don't interest me much - like google's or microsoft's robots that i have identified, or my company's own ip (we have static IP for hosting and mail server), so i have a table holding those ips.

I have query's to get the access data both by pages and by date range, however, i need to show the full access history on all IPs except the ones on my excluded IPs table - for those i only want the first access of each day

**EDIT:** per request, here's an example of what i need:
Here's a sample with tables/data (also on [sqlfiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c21552/1/0))

```
create table access (
  id int(11),
  accessDate datetime,
  ip varchar(15),
  referer varchar(150),
  landPage varchar(150)
);
create table removed (
  ip varchar(15)
);
insert into access (id, accessDate, ip, referer, landPage) values (1, '2015-08-25 12:22:24', '123.123.123.123', 'www.google.com', 'www.mydomain.com');
insert into access (id, accessDate, ip, referer, landPage) values (2, '2015-08-25 12:25:24', '123.123.123.123', 'www.mydomain.com', 'www.mydomain.com/sub1');
insert into access (id, accessDate, ip, referer, landPage) values (3, '2015-08-25 13:22:24', '103.123.123.123', 'www.google.com', 'www.mydomain.com');
insert into access (id, accessDate, ip, referer, landPage) values (4, '2015-08-25 13:23:24', '103.123.123.123', 'www.mydomain.com', 'www.mydomain.com/sub1');
insert into access (id, accessDate, ip, referer, landPage) values (5, '2015-08-26 12:22:24', '123.123.123.123', 'www.google.com', 'www.mydomain.com');
insert into removed (ip) values ('123.123.123.123');
```

I need a query that would return something like:

```
1 2015-08-25 12:22:24 123.123.123.123 www.google.com www.mydomain.com
3 2015-08-25 13:22:24 103.123.123.123 www.google.com www.mydomain.com
4 2015-08-25 13:23:24 103.123.123.123 www.mydomain.com www.mydomain.com/sub1
5 2015-08-26 12:22:24 123.123.123.123 www.google.com www.mydomain.com
```

Basically, it would show all entries for IP 103.123.123.123 since it isn't in table `removed` while showing only the first entry of IP 123.123.123.123 of each day since it is in table removed.

Is this possible?

Comment: What @Strawberry wrote - possible, and very best of luck.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Actually, not at all possible as the OP describes the problem.  There is no time column in the proposed data -- hence, no way to get the first access per day.  Alas.  Sample data and desired results help almost any question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff actually i do have a datetime field in the access table - naturally - otherwise what would be the use of it and how could i claim to query by date range as i do?

Comment: @Strawberry - you say it's possible - any pointers on how?

Comment: @N.B. - any pointers?

Comment: @Strawberry - done and done (not that it adds anything really)

Comment: I bet it 'adds' an answer!

Comment: @Strawberry - not so far - what i meant was it didn't add any better view of the problem at hand - just sample data for tests that anyone actually wanting to answer could come up with

Comment: Are you interested in the `referer` and `landPage` values for the first visit of the day from removed IPs? (There's a very easy way to do this if you're not, but a much harder way if you are.)

Comment: The provision of a data set and a corresponding result set clarified the problem, and besides it shouldn't be the responsibility of respondents to do your legwork for you.

Comment: @MarkBannister - for those specific cases... i could do without

Comment: @Strawberry - no legwork involved - i only threw up fake data in there - actually i could have had the access table with only a datetime and a val fields with the val having to be checked against a val fielde in the other table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Strawberry's previous answer, there is a trick that would work, provided you don't really care about the row returned for removed IP.

```
SELECT access.*
FROM access
LEFT JOIN removed ON removed.ip = access.ip
GROUP BY DATE(accessDate), IF(removed.ip IS NULL,access.id,removed.ip);
```

Returns:

```
+------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| id   | accessDate          | ip              | referer          | landPage              |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------------+
|    1 | 2015-08-25 12:22:24 | 123.123.123.123 | www.google.com   | www.mydomain.com      |
|    3 | 2015-08-25 13:22:24 | 103.123.123.123 | www.google.com   | www.mydomain.com      |
|    4 | 2015-08-25 13:23:24 | 103.123.123.123 | www.mydomain.com | www.mydomain.com/sub1 |
|    5 | 2015-08-26 12:22:24 | 123.123.123.123 | www.google.com   | www.mydomain.com      |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------------+
```

Explanation: First the rows are grouped by date (that part is pretty obvious). Then the rows that have a removed ip are grouped by ip (to only keep one row for each) while the others are left untouched (grouped by a unique field = no grouping happening).

Again, this is just a trick that works if do not care what row is being returned for removed ip.

Comment: :o could it be that simple??  -  will test and get back to you - and yes i only care about the data in access table - the removed table is only there to identify the IPs i want full history and those i don't

Comment: Could you explain what's happenning here? You left join the tables and groub by date (wich shouldn't do anything since every date is unique - every group will have a single element) then you group by... either id or ip? is that it?

Comment: @537mfb Yes that's it. I edited my answer with explanations.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table access (
  id int(11),
  accessDate datetime,
  ip varchar(15),
  referer varchar(150),
  landPage varchar(150)
);
create table removed (
  ip varchar(15)
);
insert into access (id, accessDate, ip, referer, landPage) values 
(1, '2015-08-25 12:22:24', '123.123.123.123', 'www.google.com', 'www.mydomain.com'),
(2, '2015-08-25 12:25:24', '123.123.123.123', 'www.mydomain.com', 'www.mydomain.com/sub1'),
(3, '2015-08-25 13:22:24', '103.123.123.123', 'www.google.com', 'www.mydomain.com'),
(4, '2015-08-25 13:23:24', '103.123.123.123', 'www.mydomain.com', 'www.mydomain.com/sub1'),
(5, '2015-08-26 12:22:24', '123.123.123.123', 'www.google.com', 'www.mydomain.com');
insert into removed (ip) values ('123.123.123.123');
```

One part of the problem...

```
SELECT a.* FROM access a LEFT JOIN removed r ON r.ip = a.ip WHERE r.ip IS NULL;
+------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| id   | accessDate          | ip              | referer          | landPage              |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------------+
|    3 | 2015-08-25 13:22:24 | 103.123.123.123 | www.google.com   | www.mydomain.com      |
|    4 | 2015-08-25 13:23:24 | 103.123.123.123 | www.mydomain.com | www.mydomain.com/sub1 |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------------+
```

Another part of the problem...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM access x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT a.ip
            , DATE(accessDate) day
            , MIN(a.accessDate) min_accessDate 
         FROM access a 
         JOIN removed r 
           ON r.ip = a.ip 
        GROUP 
           BY a.ip
            , day
     ) y 
    ON y.ip = x.ip 
   AND y.day = DATE(accessDate) 
   AND y.min_accessDate = x.accessDate;
+------+---------------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+
| id   | accessDate          | ip              | referer        | landPage         |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+
|    1 | 2015-08-25 12:22:24 | 123.123.123.123 | www.google.com | www.mydomain.com |
|    5 | 2015-08-26 12:22:24 | 123.123.123.123 | www.google.com | www.mydomain.com |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+
```

Putting it all together...

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM access a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN removed r 
    ON r.ip = a.ip 
 WHERE r.ip IS NULL

 UNION

SELECT x.* 
  FROM access x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT a.ip
            , DATE(accessDate) day
            , MIN(a.accessDate) min_accessDate 
         FROM access a 
         JOIN removed r 
           ON r.ip = a.ip 
        GROUP 
           BY a.ip
            , day
     ) y 
    ON y.ip = x.ip 
   AND y.day = DATE(accessDate) 
   AND y.min_accessDate = x.accessDate;

+------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| id   | accessDate          | ip              | referer          | landPage              |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------------+
|    3 | 2015-08-25 13:22:24 | 103.123.123.123 | www.google.com   | www.mydomain.com      |
|    4 | 2015-08-25 13:23:24 | 103.123.123.123 | www.mydomain.com | www.mydomain.com/sub1 |
|    1 | 2015-08-25 12:22:24 | 123.123.123.123 | www.google.com   | www.mydomain.com      |
|    5 | 2015-08-26 12:22:24 | 123.123.123.123 | www.google.com   | www.mydomain.com      |
+------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: interesting one - complex though - will run tests for sure - i'll have to do a select on that union though - so that the two datas won't be split up but looks promising